# Isomorphisms, & Automorphism of groupoids

Tags: group-theory

This is a two part proof:
(1) Prove that every group is the group of isomorphisms of a groupoid.
           (Can someone give me a simple explanation of what a groupoid is?)
(2) Prove that every group is the group of automorphisms of some object in some category.

Other than the question above? I need help structuring the proofs of the questions. Also, does (1) imply (2)?

Comment: A [groupoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) or a [groupoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the first one

Comment: Are you sure? In what context this excersize was given?

Comment: It is in the Aluffi Book Chapter 0 in Chapter 1 about set theory and section 4 of morphisms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a category with a single object $X$ and let $\operatorname{Mor}(X,X)=G$ with the group operation as composition.
This answers both parts.

Comment: Aren't the isomorphisms of this groupoid the *automorphisms* of $G$?

Comment: Yes, groupoid automorphisms are category automorphism. So you've answered (2) but not (1).